# Displaying joined users on a certain event

Tags: c#

I just want to ask how to display the unique joined users in our system, because I made an event management system in *Visual Studio 2013*, and I want to display how many participated to my certain created event already. I've tried a code but it doesn't work, it doesn't have errors, but it's not working. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Here's my code:

```
private void tbx_joined_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Query = "select count(distinct d.jusername) from dbems.db_join d, dbems.create_event c where d.jeventname = c.eventname";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(db.mystring());
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                //"count(distinct d.jusername)"
                string evjoined = myReader.GetInt32(Query).ToString();

                tbx_joined.Text = evjoined;

            }
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: did this solution work for you?

Comment: I'm gonna try it, even though I don't know how to use it. Where will I input that query? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Use `cmdDataBase.ExecuteScalar` without `while` loop.

Comment: @benjamingopez I thought that my new query will simply replace the query you posted.  I didn't test out your IO.  Petrov, probably made a good point.  If you still need, I can try this out tomorrow.

Comment: @BenjaminGopez You can probably figure out your issue, by yourself, using this link as an example:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script you run to fix your tables and data:

```
--USE your db here
USE [Breaz]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dbemEvent]    Script Date: 5/10/2017 4:01:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbemEvent](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EventName] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbemEvent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dbemUser]    Script Date: 5/10/2017 4:01:15 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbemUser](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Event] [int] NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](15) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbemUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbemEvent] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemEvent] ([Id], [EventName]) VALUES (1, N'School')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemEvent] ([Id], [EventName]) VALUES (2, N'Home')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbemEvent] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] ([Id], [Event], [UserName]) VALUES (1, 1, N'Bob')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] ([Id], [Event], [UserName]) VALUES (2, 1, N'Ken')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] ([Id], [Event], [UserName]) VALUES (3, 2, N'Nick')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] ([Id], [Event], [UserName]) VALUES (4, 2, N'Jack')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbemUser] OFF
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dbemUser]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbemUser_dbemEvent] FOREIGN KEY([Event])
REFERENCES [dbo].[dbemEvent] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dbemUser] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbemUser_dbemEvent]
GO
```

Here is the new query that you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.id)
FROM dbemUser u JOIN
dbemEvent e 
ON u.Event = e.Id
WHERE e.EventName = 'Home'
```